# Can I use a map's iterator type as its mapped type?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a tree whose nodes are large strings.  I don't really need to navigate the tree other than to follow the path from a node back to the root, so it suffices for each node to consist of the string and a pointer to its parent.  I also need to be able to quickly find strings in the tree.  The nodes of the tree themselves are not ordered, so this would require some sort of index.  However, the strings are big enough that I would rather not duplicate them by storing them both in my tree and in my index.

I could implement both my tree and the index with a single std::map if the key for the map was the string and the mapped value was the pointer to its parent.  However, I cannot figure out a way to write either of these types.  My best guess would be something like this:

```cpp
using Tree = std::map<std::string, typename Tree::const_iterator>;
```

or maybe:

```cpp
using Node = std::pair<std::string const, typename Node const*>;
using Tree = std::map<std::string, Node const*>;
```

But these recursive type definitions don't compile.  Is there any way to create this type in C++?  Or a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: This seems like a bit of an abuse of containers. For me personally, a container should not be used as the primary data structure for any non-trivial type. You can make it work, but very quickly you'll find that you blur the lines between interface and implementation. If you care about that, you'll end up wrapping this inside your own class, and then the "quick-and-easy" approach you currently use will seem less and less useful. If you're concerned about memory footprint for overlapping/related structures, look into Boost's intrusive container library. It's great, and more performant too.

Comment: *However, the strings are big enough that I would rather not duplicate them by storing them both in my tree and in my index.* -- Have you considered using `std::string_view`, thus not needing to duplicate entire strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the iterator in a type of your own and reference that type instead to avoid the recurisve type problem.

```cpp
struct const_iterator_wrapper {
    using iterator_type = map<string, const_iterator_wrapper>::const_iterator;

    iterator_type iter;

    const_iterator_wrapper() {}
    const_iterator_wrapper(iterator_type _iter) : iter(_iter) {}
};

using tree = map<string, const_iterator_wrapper>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `using Node` definition doesn't compile, but an actual structure would:

```
struct Node {
    std::string const s;
    Node const* n;
};
```

Comment: Yes, but this struct is unrelated to the entries in a map.  I was hoping to make a map entry (or the pair it contains) point to another map entry.

Answer (score 0):

It was not mentioned whether or not a node's parent might change after creation. If it does not, then a `set` might be a better fit than a `map`. (If it does change, then the `set` option is not completely off the table, but it might require weakening `const` correctness guarantees, possibly by making the parent pointer `mutable`.) In fact, you might not have to change your data structure much to use a `set`.

Let's say your nodes currently look like the following.

```cpp
struct Node {
    std::string data;
    const Node * parent; // Might need to add `const`
};
```

You want these sorted by the data, ignoring the parent pointer. This might require defining a new function. If the following `operator<` is already defined as something else, then it takes a little more work to define your `set`, but still not hard.

```cpp
bool operator<(const Node &a, const Node &b) {
    return a.data < b.data;
}
```

This is all you need to define a set of these nodes that will function much like your desired map.

```cpp
std::set<Node> tree;

// Add a root element.
auto result = tree.emplace("root", nullptr);
auto root_it = result.first;

// Add a child to the root.
tree.emplace("child", &*root_it);
// The `&*` combination may look odd. It is, though, a way to
// convert an iterator to a pointer.
```

There are a few gotchas that some people might find unexpected, but nothing other than what comes from using a `map` for this role.

In the end, as far as the structure of the data is concerned, a `map<K, const V>` is equivalent to a `set<pair<K, V>>` with a suitable comparison function. While the member functions differ, the biggest real functional difference between a map and a set of pairs is that the map's values can be changed (hence `const V` instead of `V` earlier).